# Does this type of real functions have a name ? What are their characteristics?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $n > 0$ be an integer. Let $f:\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R_0$ be a symmetric function such that the $(n+1) \times k$ matrix

\begin{equation}
\mathbb M=
\begin{pmatrix}
f(s_{k-n+1},s_1) & \ldots & f(s_{k-n+1},s_k)\\
\vdots &  & \vdots \\
f(s_{k+1},s_1) & \ldots & f(s_{k+1},s_k)\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

has at most $n$ linearly independent rows for any $k>n$ and real sequence $s_1<s_2<\ldots<s_{k+1}$. What does that say about $f$ ? Do such function have a name ? What are their characteristics/properties ? Is there an easier "definition" that would be equivalent, without matrices for example? Or a stronger "easier" property that would imply the above property ?

Comment: If you take $k=n+1$ you have a square matrix, and you are asking precisely that the déterminant is 0. Probably a similari approach would settle the general case by the Rouché Capelli Theorem. If $f$ is a rational function, then the condition would extend to all the $s_i$, because you can reduce the condition to a polynomial $=0$ on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Tha same holds if $f$ is a quotient of analytic functions because you get something like $\sum (something) s_1^{\alpha_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot  s_k ^{\alpha_k} $ which implies something to be zero.

Comment: Now that you have removed the $s_i < s_j$ constraint in the smooth case I would try to plug in some special values and see what happens, starting from $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case, but it is also a broad class. It isthe exact solution if $n=1$. If you take $f(x, y) = h(\min \{ x, y\} ) g(\max \{x,y\} ) $, then the first $(k-n+1) $ columns are multiple of $( g(s_{k+n-1}), \ldots , g(s_{k+1}) ) $ . The rank remain then unchanged if we discard the first $k-n$ columns; now we have $k-(k-n) = n $ columns, so that the rank is at most $n$ as desired. Note also that such functions are symmetric.

Conversely, suppose $n=1$ and set $k=2$. Taking determinant one obtains (the function is never zero)

$$ \frac{ f(s_2, s_2) }{ f(s_3, s_2) } = \frac{ f(s_2, s_1) }{f(s_3, s_1) } $$

Which means that the quotient on the right does not depend on $s_1 < s_2$. Taking $s_3 = L$ very big we get that for all $s_1 < s_2 < L$ :

$$ f(s_2, s_1) = \frac{ f(s_2, s_2) }{f(L, s_2) } f(L, s_1) = g(s_2) \cdot h(s_1) $$

By symmetry we will have that for $s_2 < s_1 < L$

$$ f(s_1, s_2) = f(s_2, s_1) = g(s_1) h(s_2) $$

So that $f(x, y) = h(\min \{x, y\}) g(\max \{x, y\}) $. We can repeat this argument for greater $L$, but since the new $h, g$ must agree with the old ones on $s_1 , s_2 < L$, we will get well defined functions $h, g$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^+$. Hope you enjoy!